# google checkout returns item unavailable

Tags: java, android, google-checkout

I'm integrating google checkout with my android application.

I have successfully tested the billing process with android.test.purchased.

but after uploading the apk (it is not published yet but is signed) and creating product list (products are published yet) I'm getting **"The item you requested is not available for purchase"** while trying to buy  an item.
in the logs I can see the response code RESPONSE_ITEM_UNAVAILABLE. google docs says that this eror code

> "Indicates that Google Play cannot find the requested item in the
>   application's product list. This can happen if the product ID is
>   misspelled in your REQUEST_PURCHASE request or if an item is
>   unpublished in the application's product list."

I have checked it twice - the item is published and is spelled correctly. and also I'm running the same version of apk on my device which is uploaded
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after publishing the application as well the checkout started to work. just wondered why they have put in docs that there is no need to publish the application but the products.